# MATLAB object representation in HDF5

Tags: matlab, hdf5

Is it possible to retrieve object properties that were saved in MATLAB with `-v7.3` in Python?

For example, take this class:

```
classdef TestClass < handle
    properties
        Name = 'Nobody';
        Value = 42;
    end
    methods
        function this = TestClass(name, value)
            if nargin > 0
                this.Name = name;
            end
            if nargin > 1
                this.Value = value;
            end
        end
        function doSomething(this)
            fprintf('My name is â%sâ and my value is â%dâ.\n', this.Name, this.Value);
        end
    end
end
```

and create and save a few objects:

```
a=TestClass('Theo', 17)
b=TestClass
c=[a,b]
d={a,b}
save('testClassF.mat', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
```

Using `hdf5` in Python, I can see that `a` is represented as

```
array([3707764736, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=uint32)
```

and `b` is

```
array([3707764736, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2], dtype=uint32).
```

A little more digging shows that `'#refs#/e'` yields `a`'s `Name`, and `'#refs#/f'` yields its `Value`. But where does the mapping occur?

Comment: Unfortunately, despite using the standard HDF5 file, MATLAB v7.3 files are poorly-documented.  Some people have had some success reverse-engineering them (check out the `hdf5storage` python package for an example), but they are apparently not really standard hdf5 files.